# Is it okay to start (end) a question with a greeting (goodbye)?

Tags: support, questions, guidelines

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should 'Hi', 'thanks' and taglines and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Is it okay to start a question on SO with:

- **Hello**
- **Hi**
- **Hello everybody**

or end it with:

- **Thank you**
- **I apreciate your help**
- **Looking forward to an answer**

or something like this?

Sometimes when I decide to ask something, I don't really know if I should start saying *Hello* or similar or saying *thank you* at the end.

Comment: maybe it is a good thing. But Dont think there is any restriction on how to use them. Its totally left to individuals. I believe this question would come under subjective and argumentive list.

Comment: I've stopped doing this, as my answers were getting comments/edits for this. I still feel it's good manners, but bow to community opinion - or at least, those parts of the community that object enough to edit/comment.

Answer (score 3):

Please don't. It adds nothing to the question. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)